# What keeps turning my screen on?

Tags: 17.10, power-management, screen

Running 17.10 64bit on an i5-3570k desktop with GTX 950 video card.  I like leaving my system on all day, but having my screen turn off after 10 minutes.  This works fine, but, many times throughout the day when not in use, the screen turns on to show my lock screen for a small period of time, then the lock screen display turns off again and shows the monitor blue before turning off.  I'd like to find out what is 'waking' it when it does this.  Is there anywhere this activity is tracked?

I've never had this issue before, but this is also the first Ubuntu release with Gnome by default, not sure if that's related.

Comment: Could it be your mouse that moves slightly when you e.g. bump into your desk?

Comment: Is it email?  I use `evolution` (mua), and my screen wakes to lock screen when using gnome on an incoming email. Also you have tagged 'suspend' but is it suspended?  (i don't see it when suspended)  Also can't answer your real question; a beep on another machine told me it was mail so I didn't look...

Comment: Nope, most days the only applications open are Firefox and Hexchat, and maybe a terminal or two.  I suppose it could be a notification coming through on firefox or something.  Maybe I'll close everything off and just leave it like that and see what happens.

Took out the 'suspend', I don't even know how that got there!  No, the system isn't suspended.